# Why HTTP run in UDP

Tags: google-chrome, http, networking, tcp, udp

As I learned in my class about Network. HTTP is run above TCP beause TCP is a reliable transfer protocol. But when I tested by `sudo netstat -tulpn` all what I'm seeing from Chrome is UDP.

[image]

Comment: What you highlight in the image is not HTTP.  Browsers can do more than HTTP, i.e. all the media transport in WebRTC is done with UDP.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely HTTP/3. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-quic-http-27.html for more information.